# i want to display my text at top-left over image how to do that

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am design a web page in html css and bootstrap everythings is ok on my laptop but wrong with another small device problem is that over on image, text are invisible

my code is

```css
#titlecolor {
  color: #ef4d3b;
}

#textonbaner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  align: left;
  color: white;
}

#sfr {
  border: 2px solid #ef4d3b;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 40%;
}


/* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  /* Set width to 100% */
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
}


/* Hide the carousel text when the screen is less than 600 pixels wide */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .carousel-caption {
    display: none;
  }
}

.service_background_color {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ef4d3b;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#areah {
  color: black;
}

#logo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 140px;
}

.citycerviceplce {
  background-color: #ef4d3b;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

.footermy {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#copyright {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>ROOM</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- ............................External css links ............................ -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!-- ............................bootstrap links ............................ -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- .............................................nav area.......................-->
  <div class="container text-center">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="pull-left">
            <img src="image/mymateroomsimg.png" id="logo">
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="pull-right titleupb">
            <h3 id="titlecolor">Rooms Available<br>
              Delhi | Agra | Mathura
            </h3>
          </span>
      </div>


      <div class="imageban">

        <img src="image/mymateroomsbanner.jpg" alt="banner" class="img-responsive" />

        <h3 id="textonbaner">Book @ 9910852431 </h3>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--.................... start here  ...............-->

    <u><h3>Let’s Get Together With</h3></u>

    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Lovely Couples </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Girls & boys</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Corporate Colligues </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>College Friends </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Corporates Cocktail </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Employees</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Awesome Weekend</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Senior Citizens</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>School’s Friends</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Aunty & Moma </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Professionals </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Entrepreneurs</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ..............Room Services are here..............................-->

    <u><h3>Room Services</h3></u>
    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Fully AC </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p> Soft Linen</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Free Breakfast</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Clean Bathroom</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Shower </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Drinking Water</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>LED TV</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Dish Cable</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Free Wifi</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Aunty & Moma </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Smoking & Non Smoking
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Seating Area</p>

      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- .................................................. Hotel Services are here.................................. -->

    <u><h3>Hotel Services</h3></u>

    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Friendly Staff </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Powerback up</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Lift </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>College Friends </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Restaurant</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>24hrs Security</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Local ID's Allowed</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>First Aid Kit</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>24 hrs Check In</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Safe and Secure</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Doctor on Call </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Family hotel </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Parking Facility</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>CCTV Cameras</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Laundry</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Geyser</p>
        24 hrs Check In

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Intercom & More...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ********************************* My Mate’s Promise  ********************************  -->

    <u><h3>My Mate’s Promise</h3></u>

    <div class="row service_background_color">

      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Couple friendly Room</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Family Stay </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>College Friends </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Secure and safe </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>No questions asked</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Local ID’s Allowed</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Book as you need</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>SILENTLY & PRIVATELY</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Unmarried couples allowed </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Priority on Check In</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Gifts on check out</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- ...................................My Mate Services.............................-->

    <u><h3>My Mate Services</h3></u>

    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Hotel Booking</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Train Tickets </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Tour Packages</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Car Rental </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>PG Accomodation </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Home Stay</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Making Get Together</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ................................... How Its Work .................................  -->
    <u><h3>How it's work </h3></u>
    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Book on Call& Confirm your Locaiton </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Discus About your Place & Price </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Pay as your way</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Receive An Email or SMS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Asked for Pick Up your place</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Show your Valid ID Proof</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Easly Check in your Room </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ................................... Locatuon .................................  -->
    <u><h3>Location</h3></u>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-4 citycerviceplce">
        <h3 id="areah">Delhi's Room</h3>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Karol Bagh</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Paharganj</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Airport</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Railway Station</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Noida</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Gurgaon</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Rajeev Chowk</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Metro Station</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Aero City</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 citycerviceplce">
        <h3 id="areah">Agra's Room</h3>
        <h4>Hotels & SPA on Fatehabad Road</h4>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Taj Mahal</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Agra Cantt Railway Station</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Agra Fort</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA on Sanjay Place Bus Stop</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Dayalbagh</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Baluganj</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 citycerviceplce">
        <h3 id="areah">Mathura's Room</h3>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Refinery</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Krishna Temple</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Agra Fort</p>
        <p>Hotels Near Railway Station </p>
        <p>Hotel & SPA On Agra Mathura Heighway</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row footermy">
      <div class="col-sm-2">My mate's room</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Team</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Privacy & Policy</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Guest Policy</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Terms & Condition </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Contact Us</div>
    </div>

    <center>
      <p id="copyright">@ copyright Mymatesrooms Rooms & Spa All Rights Reserved. </p>
    </center>

  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to solve that problem with css but when I open a small device then text ore hidden.

Comment: Create a working sample on jsfiddle or codepen with *only* what is required to produce the problem.

Comment: give me some idea how to do that please?

Comment: `but wrong with another small device problem is that over on image` I dont see antthing happend when i run it in bigger screen and hover on image

Comment: Here are the links: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) || [codepen](https://codepen.io/). Create an account and create and save a sample you can share.

Comment: I created for him : https://jsfiddle.net/kn82ze7j/

Comment: Thanks. He's saying the problem is on a small screen. I don't think 'hover' but  'over'; could be wrong.

Comment: right... but what text?? @manish kumar yadav please explain a little bit more

Comment: @manish kumar yadav you dont see the text because it colored white and when you reduce the screen it moves (and the background is white also and you dont see it)

Comment: Give `position: absolute` to the text

Comment: @manishkumaryadav see here how to set text over image:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Answer (score 0):

You made 2 mistakes in your code. One especially regarding to bootstrap usage and one rudimentary CSS misunderstandings.

1. There should only be 2 col (col-md-6 in your case)elements directly under a row in Bootstrap. Your imageban was the third element, so I moved it out of the row to make sure behaviour of bootstrap grid is correctly.
2. To position the text absolute oriented on the banner, the banner itself has to have `position: relative;`. Currently text is oriented 130px from top to the whole page, so on small devices, when banner is pushed down, banner is far more down but text is still the same 130px away from top.

I fixed that and set bannertext top value to 0, so it is 0px from banner now instead 130px from page top.

I fixed both on below code snipped.

```css
.imageban {
  position: relative;
}

#titlecolor {
  color: #ef4d3b;
}

#textonbaner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
}

#sfr {
  border: 2px solid #ef4d3b;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 40%;
}


/* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  /* Set width to 100% */
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
}


/* Hide the carousel text when the screen is less than 600 pixels wide */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .carousel-caption {
    display: none;
  }
}

.service_background_color {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ef4d3b;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#areah {
  color: black;
}

#logo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 140px;
}

.citycerviceplce {
  background-color: #ef4d3b;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

.footermy {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#copyright {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>ROOM</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- ............................External css links ............................ -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!-- ............................bootstrap links ............................ -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- .............................................nav area.......................-->
  <div class="container text-center">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="pull-left">
            <img src="image/mymateroomsimg.png" id="logo">
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="pull-right titleupb">
            <h3 id="titlecolor">Rooms Available<br>
              Delhi | Agra | Mathura
            </h3>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="imageban">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x500/55a7eb/fff" alt="banner" class="img-responsive" />

      <h3 id="textonbaner">Book @ 9910852431 </h3>

    </div>

    <!--.................... start here  ...............-->

    <u><h3>Let’s Get Together With</h3></u>

    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Lovely Couples </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Girls & boys</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Corporate Colligues </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>College Friends </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Corporates Cocktail </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Employees</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Awesome Weekend</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Senior Citizens</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>School’s Friends</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Aunty & Moma </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Professionals </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Entrepreneurs</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ..............Room Services are here..............................-->

    <u><h3>Room Services</h3></u>
    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Fully AC </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p> Soft Linen</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Free Breakfast</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Clean Bathroom</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Shower </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Drinking Water</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>LED TV</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Dish Cable</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Free Wifi</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Aunty & Moma </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Smoking & Non Smoking
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Seating Area</p>

      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- .................................................. Hotel Services are here.................................. -->

    <u><h3>Hotel Services</h3></u>

    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Friendly Staff </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Powerback up</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Lift </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>College Friends </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Restaurant</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>24hrs Security</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Local ID's Allowed</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>First Aid Kit</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>24 hrs Check In</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Safe and Secure</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Doctor on Call </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Family hotel </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Parking Facility</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>CCTV Cameras</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Laundry</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Geyser</p>
        24 hrs Check In

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Intercom & More...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ********************************* My Mate’s Promise  ********************************  -->

    <u><h3>My Mate’s Promise</h3></u>

    <div class="row service_background_color">

      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Couple friendly Room</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Family Stay </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>College Friends </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Secure and safe </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>No questions asked</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Local ID’s Allowed</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Book as you need</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>SILENTLY & PRIVATELY</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Unmarried couples allowed </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Priority on Check In</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Gifts on check out</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- ...................................My Mate Services.............................-->

    <u><h3>My Mate Services</h3></u>

    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Hotel Booking</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Train Tickets </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Tour Packages</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Car Rental </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>PG Accomodation </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Home Stay</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Making Get Together</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ................................... How Its Work .................................  -->
    <u><h3>How it's work </h3></u>
    <div class="row service_background_color">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Book on Call& Confirm your Locaiton </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Discus About your Place & Price </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Pay as your way</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Receive An Email or SMS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <p>Asked for Pick Up your place</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Show your Valid ID Proof</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Easly Check in your Room </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ................................... Locatuon .................................  -->
    <u><h3>Location</h3></u>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-4 citycerviceplce">
        <h3 id="areah">Delhi's Room</h3>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Karol Bagh</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Paharganj</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Airport</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Railway Station</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Noida</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Gurgaon</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Rajeev Chowk</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Metro Station</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Aero City</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 citycerviceplce">
        <h3 id="areah">Agra's Room</h3>
        <h4>Hotels & SPA on Fatehabad Road</h4>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Taj Mahal</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Agra Cantt Railway Station</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Agra Fort</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA on Sanjay Place Bus Stop</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Dayalbagh</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA in Baluganj</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 citycerviceplce">
        <h3 id="areah">Mathura's Room</h3>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Refinery</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Krishna Temple</p>
        <p>Hotels & SPA Near Agra Fort</p>
        <p>Hotels Near Railway Station </p>
        <p>Hotel & SPA On Agra Mathura Heighway</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row footermy">
      <div class="col-sm-2">My mate's room</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Team</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Privacy & Policy</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Guest Policy</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Terms & Condition </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Contact Us</div>
    </div>

    <center>
      <p id="copyright">@ copyright Mymatesrooms Rooms & Spa All Rights Reserved. </p>
    </center>

  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks bro i try your sniped code and finally solved my problem .